Excel Matching multiple values from 2 different sheets
I have 2 excel sheets, first one is the value I expected from a customer. The second one is what customers pays me. I want to check if customer paid me as I expected.
Here is an important note, I have a tolerance which is -10, +10. I mean in the table below I can accept price range from 529 to 549 (in the example I can't accept because price is 519 which is out of my range).
The important thing is, datas are in completely different order.
First sheet is like this ( what I expect),



ID
Date
Category
Price
**




12345678910
01/2024
20
539



34561234516
01/2024
20
123456,50




Second sheet is like this ( customer pays)



ID
Date
Category
Price
**




345612346516
01/2024
20
12344,50



12345678910
01/2024
20
519




I have 2 excel sheets, first one is the value I expected from a customer. The second one is what customers pays me. I want to check if customer paid me as I expected.
When I match them I want to write "ok" to next column.
What I have tried; VLOOKUP is just bringing me the first data therefore If there are duplicates I cannot match them. I tried INDEX but also doesn't work.

May be something like this you could try: =IF(OR(ABS(D2-FILTER($J$2:$J$4,A2=$G$2:$G$4,0))<=10),"Ok","Not Ok") with proper sheet reference : =IF(OR(ABS(D2-FILTER(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$4,A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0))<=10),"Ok","Not Ok")

With your sample non will match. From what you wrote in the last part, it seems you're looking for a way to sum payments with same reference. Vlookup will only return first found item. Filter or Sum(product) will return (the sum of) multiple lines meeting your criteria.

Yes @P.b Sir, as per the example given none is going to match. Also, its not clear about what they want to do when there is a duplicate!

Maybe value minus SUMIF result to check the remainder

Thank you for your ideas, I will check duplicates and if I find one I will wrote "repeated" to another column

Use an array formula with INDEX and MATCH to handle this in Excel.
=IF(AND((INDEX(Sheet1!D:D, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0)) - 10) <= D2, D2 <= (INDEX(Sheet1!D:D, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A, 0)) + 10)), "OK", "Not OK")

